# Make clickable bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, hyperref, citing, multiple-citations

Thanks to the following just before `\end{document}`

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} % Bibliography
\bibliography{References}
```

Then, in my preamble,

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks = true,
linkcolor = blue,
linkbordercolor = {white},
citecolor = blue,
```

A correct `.bib` file and `\cite{}` as well, I've managed to make my citations in my memoir clickable, which is super cool.
However, I'd like to know if references IN the bibliography can be clickable and redirect into the first time it is referenced (as it can be multiple times referenced), with an arrow for instance.

Note that this functionality is well implemented in nearly all [wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikip%C3%A9dia:WikiLove#cite_ref-1) articles with at least one reference.

Please consider easiest solutions as much as possible :)

Comment: Please convert your code snippets into a complete minimal working example (MWE) showing your document class and the required packages.

Comment: The feature you are looking for is called `backref`. Maybe you can find something useful with this search term